# Eclipse Formatter: Enums and Constructor

Tags: c++, eclipse

i try to apply some guidelines for my code formatter in eclipse, but i have a problem with two things:
at first, enum Classes:

What I expect after formatting:

```
enum class Type : uint8_t 
{
    first = 1,
    second = 2,
    third = 3
}
```

What i get after formatting:

```
enum class Type
    : uint8_t {
        first = 1, 
    second = 2, 
    third = 3
}
```

The second thing are constructors:
Again, what i expect:

```
Example::Example(int x) :
    _x(x)
{
}
```

And what i get:

```
Example::Example(int x) :
        _x(x)
{
}
```

So I have to change the line break of Enums and the indention of the assigment list of constructors. But sadly I dont find this options..
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the formatting options using the `Project Properties->C/C++ General->Formatter` tab:

[image]

Using `Edit` the following window with all the options pops up:

[image]

Regarding `enum` declarations it seems only line wrapping options can be controlled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now i found out how to change the constructor thing. But i do not find any option, to get the enum class formatted correctly. Do you know where i can find this option?